# GTM Cookie Variable Value Clears while Cookie is still set

Tags: cookies, google-tag-manager

I'm working on a tracking system that uses a GTM Container to selectively display a tracking pixel but I'm running into a bit of a snag.

The setup basically depends on a client-side cookie that gets set when the user first visits the site based on a parameter in the URL string. Currently this part works fine and the cookie gets set to the appropriate value.

The issue is that the GTM Variable which is set up to get the value of the 1st party cookie seems to not be able to actually get the value after the first page. The cookie still appears to be set in the browser so I can't figure out why this would happen. It's like when GTM refreshes the variable values on the page change it doesn't see the cookie the second time for some reason.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this would be really appreciated!!!

UPDATE: I figured out that the issue was in how my GTM is reading the cookie. The transition that seems to throw it off it from my Wordpress/cart path to my Wordpress/checkout path. I'm wondering how I might make the cookie less specific so that it won't be constrained to such a discrete path. It appears that currently I can access it anywhere on the Wordpress/cart/* path but not in Wordpress/*

I'm setting the cookie like so in a GTM custom js variable:

```
function() {
  return function(name, value, ms, path, domain) {
    if (!name || !value) {
      return;
    }
    var d;
    var cpath = path ? '; path=' + path : '';
    var cdomain = domain ? '; domain=' + domain : '';
    var expires = '';
    if (ms) {
      d = new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime() + ms);
      expires = '; expires=' + d.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + cpath + cdomain;
  }
}
```

Using a GTM tag that fires on every page and checks for the presence of the cookie like so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var source = '';
  if (window.location.search.indexOf('source=network1') !== -1) {
    source = 'network1';
  } else if (window.location.search.indexOf('source=network2') !== -1) {
    source = 'network2';

  }
  {{setCookieHelper}}('source', source, 2592000000);
</script>
```

Any thoughts on how to avoid having the path be so specific for this cookie would be really appreciated.

Comment: Maybe GTM is run before the client side code that sets the cookie ? Or does this even happen when the cookie is there from a previous visit ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think that's it as it happens on a transition in the path. Check out my edits :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long and drawn out review of a lot of documentation I realized that the way that document.cookie sets the path of the cookie uses the current page as a the default.

For example, if server 123.123.123.123 sets a cookie using JS from a file at 123.123.123.123/folder/test/index.php then the path parameter of the cookie will be set to /folder/test/ as the default.

This is an issue because if you use a wordpress cart of are changing directories for some reason you will lose access to the cookies stored under that path. (For example if you had someone go form /folder/test to /folder/checkout/ the cookie will no longer be visible to GTM)

Hope this helps someone!